# Error extracting year when converting date to text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a cell with a date, formatted as a date, in Excel 2016.

When I insert a function like the following...

```
=TEXT(L1;"yyyy")
```

I expect to get a string like "1980". Instead I get the text "yyyy" in the cell.

However, if I do this...

```
=TEXT(L1;"yyyy-MM-dd")
```

...I instead get a text like "yyyy-05-25"

In other words, no matter what I try, I can't seem to get the year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string you pass to `TEXT` depends on the language your MS Office pack is made for. For examlple, you will need to set your format string to "aaaa" in French or "jjjj" in German to get the 4-digit year.

Comment: Weird thing is, I have the English language pack for Office, yet I have to put in "åååå" to get the year - possibly because of Swedish region settings on my computer. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

it's uppercase Y in the format. any letter that is not defined gets copied literally, so you are using lowercase y and it gets just copied.

Use TEXT(L1;"YYYY-MM-DD"), and you should be fine.

Comment: I tried both "yyyy" and "YYYY", but it made no difference. Thinking it might be because of English Office version on a computer with Swedish region settings?

Comment: yes, the other answer says that, i did not realize that this might be language specific. I worked for years with a German windows, but always had it set to English date formats, so it never appeared to me.
Well I'm glad you got a solution.

Comment: @WillP. I believe "y" and "Y" both work in English version. Both "m" and "M" mean month, that's for sure.